# What is happening when digitalWrite(pinname, LOW) is invoked after pinMode(pinname, INPUT_PULLUP)?

Tags: voltage, input, electricity, pull-up

I read the Arduino official docs on digitalWrite and am confused about what is happening from an electrical perspective when digitalWrite is invoked on INPUT_PULLUP pins.

Say my code says this:

```
pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
digitalWrite(4, LOW);
```

The docs say:

> If the pin is configured as an INPUT, digitalWrite() will enable
> (HIGH) or disable (LOW) the internal pullup on the input pin. It is
> recommended to set the pinMode() to INPUT_PULLUP to enable the
> internal pull-up resistor. See the Digital Pins tutorial for more
> information.

Does this mean pin 4 is floating or is it at ground?  Are those two lines of code equivalent to `pinMode(4, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(LOW);`  ?

Comment: look at section 14.2 of https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I a noob in EE and arduino so I think I need some help understanding what this doc means.  I'm trying to get at what kind of behavior to expect.  Are you also saying this is chip dependent?

Comment: definitely chip dependent, but probably very much the similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty explicitly stated there in your quote: if you write a LOW when in INPUT mode it disables the pullup resistor. That's all it does.

```cpp
pinMode(4, INPUT);
digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
```

is exactly the same as:

```cpp
pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

And

```cpp
pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLUP);
digitalWrite(4, LOW);
```

is exactly the same as

```
pinMode(4, INPUT);
```

Of course this exploits a peculiarity of the AVR's IO block, but any decent core will emulate that functionality for compatibility with older code.

Comment: Thanks, can you address the part of the question about if `pinMode(4, INPUT);` leaves the pin floating or if it is at GND?

Comment: A pin set to INPUT with no pullup and not connected to anything is *always* floating. It can never output anything or be set to any level unless it is explicitly set to OUTPUT.